# ALEPlots for categorical variables in classification model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am trying to create an ALE plot for a categorical variable in a classification randomforest model. My ALE plot code works for continuous variables:

```
#packages
library(randomForest)
library(ALEPlot)
library(iml)

# create sample data frame
data <- data.frame(mortality = as.factor(c(rep("Low", 200), rep("High", 200))),
                   veg = as.factor(rep(c("Shrub", "Oak", "conifer", "forb"), each = 50)),
                   slope = rep(seq(0,90), length = 200))

# random forest model 
rfm <- randomForest(mortality ~., data = data)


# ALE plot
low_predictor <- Predictor$new(rfm, data = data, type = "prob", class="Low")
high_predictor <- Predictor$new(rfm, data = data, type = "prob", class="High")

## Vegetation variable 
low_veg <- plot(FeatureEffect$new(low_predictor, feature = "veg", method = "ale")) 
high_veg <- plot(FeatureEffect$new(high_predictor, feature = "veg", method = "ale")) 

plot(low_veg)
plot(high_veg)

## slope variable
low_slope <- plot(FeatureEffect$new(low_predictor, feature = "slope", method = "ale")) 
high_slope <- plot(FeatureEffect$new(high_predictor, feature = "slope", method = "ale")) 

plot(low_slope)
plot(high_slope)
```

I get the error:

> "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument
> 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': non-numeric argument to
> binary operator"

The response variable is binary and the categorical variable has 4 classes.

If I change the method from "ale" to "pdp" the code also works, but just not when I try to make an ale plot. Has anyone else run into this problem? Maybe ale plots cannot be created for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the error. The code ran through and produced the ALE plots when I tested it.
(btw. there is a typo in the script it should be low_predictor, not Low_predictor).

Make sure that you start the code in a fresh R session. Do you have the latest version of iml installed?
It also might help if you could share the entire output.

What is the output you get for
`FeatureEffect$new(Low_predictor, feature = "veg", method = "ale")$results`?

Comment: If I follow that script, then I get this error "Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator". The iml package is up to date.

Comment: I updated my post to include a reproducible sample